# Power BI - Values section

Tags: powerbi, distinct-values

I noticed that the Values section in the visualization field automatically counts the distinct values. I believe that is a standard with Power Bi... How can I change it to where it counts all values?

[image]
[[image]]

Comment: Is your Count a column or a measure?

Comment: It is a measure

Comment: If it’s a measure, then you need to modify the measure. You aren’t intended to add aggregations on top of defined measures.

Answer (score 0):

In the Values section, notice the down arrow next to the X on the right. Click on that to show the dropdown menu where you can choose the aggregation that you prefer.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is there a reason I might not be seeing those functions? I added the screenshot on my original post of what I see when I click the down arrow.